# Comparing two StructType schemas with differing number of columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In Spark 3.1.1+

Is there a way to diff two StructType schemas if they have a different number of columns, where column types can also differ for the same column name?

For example:

Schema 1:

```
StructType {
  column_a: Int,
  column_b: StructType {
    column_c: Int,
    column_d: String
  }
}
```

Schema 2:

```
StructType {
  column_a: String
}
```

So I essentially want to know that `column_a` was updated to a different type, and `column_b` (along with everything under it) was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `diff` function available in standard scala arrays.
This will give elements in the first schema but not in the second.

##### Tree Structure

```scala
schema1.printTreeString()
/*
root
|-- column_a: integer (nullable = true)
|-- column_b: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- column_c: integer (nullable = true)
|    |-- column_d: string (nullable = true)
|-- column_e: integer (nullable = true)
*/

schema2.printTreeString()
/*
root
|-- column_a: string (nullable = true)
|-- column_e: integer (nullable = true)
*/
```

##### Perform Diff

```scala
val diff = schema1.fields.diff(schema2.fields)
val diffSchema = StructType(diff)

diffSchema.printTreeString()
/*
root
 |-- column_a: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- column_b: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- column_c: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- column_d: string (nullable = true)
*/
```

Refer to [this link](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.4/scala/collection/Seq.html#diff%5BB%3E:A%5D(that:scala.collection.Seq%5BB%5D):C) for more info on the diff function.